# Why are mushrooms growing from the base of my potted avocado tree?

Tags: houseplants, avocado, mushrooms, wilt

My avocado tree was doing fine, until I noticed it begin to wilt, although her sister was doing fine.

I didn't know what fertilizers to give it first, but later I noticed mushrooms growing at its roots. They are what's making it wilt.

Is it enough to remove the mushrooms only, or will they just grow again?
What shall I give it to come back to life?

This is a picture of the avocado with mushrooms:

[image]

and here is the picture of it with her sister:

[image]

Comment: the mushrooms didn't kill the plant. They are just taking advantage of it being dead.

Comment: Unrelated, did you pinch out the sister? I find indoor avocados turn into proverbial beans stalks and lack the space to be practical : perhaps this is a solution?

Comment: I'm planning to plant them in the garden soon, but I was not sure of the possibility of growing up, ill try to transplant it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mushrooms are simply the fruiting bodies of mycelium present in the compost. To check whether the plant is revivable or not, scrape back a little of the bark or outer covering on the main stem with your fingernail in a few places, particularly towards the lower part of the stem. If beneath is brown and dry, it's dead - if it looks moist and greenish, then turn it out of the pot, shake the compost off, rinse the roots in water, and repot using fresh compost in a clean pot.

There seems to be an issue with watering and/or humidity. If the brown leaves on the 'live' plant went soggy and then brown, overwatering. If they went dry and crispy and brown, underwatering.